# Why is a connection to adminer inside a docker container stuck in infinite loading?

Tags: postgresql, docker, raspberry-pi, adminer

I have a postgres docker instance running on my Raspberry PI.

In addition I want to access the database with adminer.
I tried to run it inside a docker container on multiple ways (see below). But every try leads to the sample problem:

When I enter the address to adminer `raspberrypiIP:5431` I am stuck in a infinite loading process, whether I try it from the Pi itself or from my normal machine.

The adminer logs indicate a connction was established:

```
Server (http://[::]:8080 started
[::connectedDeviceIP]:port Accepted
```

Can anybody help me with that? I couldn't find a valid solution. Below are my docker tries: They match with the most other in the docs or other troubleshooting threads. I am out of ideas.

I tried to run adminer with a **docker compose**:

```
version: "2"

services:
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - 5431:8080
        container_name: adminer
```

As **docker run**:

```
docker run -p 5431:8080 adminer
```

And as a container created with **portainer**.

All lead to the described problem. (If I start the docker-compose with my normal Ubuntu machine adminer is reachable. So the problem might be related to the Raspberr PI, but shouldn't that be fine with the docker abstraction?)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a solution, but I can confirm this is happening to me on Raspberry Pi as well. Same situation: Docker container. Connection is accepted, but the browser continues with a 'busy' indicator as if it's waiting for something to be sent, but it's not getting there. Just for fun, I skipped port redirection in favor of --network=host, but got the same results. So far, it does seem to be unique to the Pi.

Comment: Same here as well. Not sure what to do

Comment: As a workaround: I could access the database in the docker container on the Pi with an adminer instance running on my development machine (also started with docker). 
I added the adminer service from above to my docker-componse that starts the development server on my ubuntu development machine. With that I could open adminer on my PC (localhost) and connect with adminer to the database on the RPI (with adding the IP address of the PI to the connection configuration).

Comment: There seems to be an issue with outdated version of libseccomp2 and docker version as described at [docker-adminer github repo](https://github.com/TimWolla/docker-adminer/issues/96#issuecomment-778519692)